# Docusign connect: what is the envelope event triggered when sender selects "Discard" action?

Tags: docusignapi

A sender has an option to discard an envelope.
I'd like to get a notification when that happens. So I subscribed to "Voided" event but have not been able to receive notification from the Docusign connect when sender discards an envelope.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Roman

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the *Discard Changes* action, as shown here?

[image]

If so, there is no DocuSign Connect event notification that correlates to this sender action.

- If the Sender were to click *Discard Changes* in the process of creating a new Envelope (i.e., one that hasn't yet been saved or sent), there wouldn't be an envelope to associate the event notification with (because the Envelope ID isn't created until it's Saved or Sent).
- If the Sender were to open an existing Envelope via the DocuSign UI (i.e., either a Draft Envelope that has never been sent or an In-Process Envelope that is pending action from one or more recipients) and click *Discard Changes* before sending or saving, there wouldn't be any Connect event notification triggered because there was no change in Envelope state.